# Does not display a logo Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

```
public class SplashPage : ContentPage
{
    Image splashImage;

    public SplashPage()
    {
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
        var sub = new AbsoluteLayout();
        splashImage = new Image
        {
            Source = "Logo.png",
            WidthRequest = 100,
            HeightRequest = 100
        };
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(splashImage, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.PositionProportional);
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(splashImage,new Rectangle(0.5,0.5,AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize,AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize));
        sub.Children.Add(splashImage);
        this.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#429de3");



    }
    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        await splashImage.ScaleTo(1, 2000);
        await splashImage.ScaleTo(0.9, 1500,Easing.Linear);
        await splashImage.ScaleTo(150, 1200, Easing.Linear);
        Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page1());
    }
}
```

I recently started studying xamarin and decided to make a splash screen, everything seems to work, the screensaver itself is there, but there is no logo on the screensaver itself, although I threw it into the drawable folder for android and into resources in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you haven't set the content of the page. You've added an image to the layout, but you haven't set the pages's Content to that layout.

Adding:

```
Content = sub;
```

will fix your problem.

If I could offer a couple of suggestions to help you debug this sort of thing in future.

A good way to test layout code is to set the background colour on individual elements. There's a great library called [Debug Rainbows](https://github.com/sthewissen/Xamarin.Forms.DebugRainbows), that'll do a lot of the work for you.

Also, try and avoid using the more complex layouts, unless you've got a good reason to do so. A simple [ContentView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/contentview) or [StackLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/stacklayout) would suffice here.

The [Xamarin Content Page's Content property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.contentpage.content?view=xamarin-forms#xamarin-forms-contentpage-content) is just a [View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/controls/views), so there's no reason you could just set the page's content to a full screen image - if you wanted to.

Have fun.

Comment: @aspect112 thank you for your help, i.e. it's enough for me to add Content = sub; to my code and everything will work?

Comment: @Johnny Yup. That's all you need to do. Give it a try and see.

If you've happy, please upvote and mark this answer as accepted. I'm trying to get a rep for providing quality Xamarin help to people here. :)

Comment: Yes, that's right, everything worked, you just need to reduce the size of the logo, don't you know how?

Comment: @Johnny without knowing exactly what you're trying to do, my suggestion would be to ensure that you've got multiple copies of the image in different resolutions, which you can see examples of in the Xamarin documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=macos#local-images

You could also just embed the images directly into your shared library (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=macos#embedded-images) and handle the sizing directly by setting HeightRequest and WidthRequest.